# LaTex word count whilst including certain packages

Tags: latex, tex, overleaf

I am trying to get an accurate representation of the words in my project, though some of the sections I would like counted are code samples within the `listings` package. Is there a way to do a word count whilst including this package?

I have researched the TeXcount command line tool and noticed it had an -includepackage= option, I tried to play around with this but I couldn't get it to work.

I am writing in Overleaf. Could anyone offer assistance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document)

Comment: No it does not show how to specify which package tags to include in the wordcount.

Comment: Most of those solutions will count all the words.  Do you just want to count the number of words within listing environments?